# How to add a string to this?

Tags: c#

How can I add a string to this:

```
public void Form1_Load(object s, EventArgs e)
{
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "maincode.txt"))) {
        sw.WriteLine("00000012{0:yyyyMMdd}{1}{0:HHmmss}", DateAndTime.Now, (new Random()).Next(0, 2) == 0 ? "0010" : "0054");
    }
}
```

I would like to specify the location via using a string. Does anyone know how i can add the string path instead of the `System.IO.Path.Combine` ?

Comment: where does the string come from?

Comment: `Path.Combine` returns a string already. What's the issue again?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit vague, however lets have a go at reading your mind....

You have not specified *what* string you want to add, or how you want to add it but here's a few options, and they all revolve around this part of your code:

```
  System.IO.Path.Combine(
      Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), 
      "maincode.txt")
```

This call to `Path.Combine` will return a string which represents a path to a file called "maincode.txt" inside the Special folder "ApplicationData".

**Option 1: You wish to instead create the same file in a sub directory**

As the `Path.Combine` method can take any number of arguments, you can just append the name of your sub directory:

```
System.IO.Path.Combine(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), 
    "SomeSubDirectory",
    "maincode.txt")
```

**Option 2: You want to replace the `GetSpecialFolder` part with a hard coded path:**

```
System.IO.Path.Combine(
    "C:\SomeHardCodedRootDir",
    "maincode.txt")
```

**Option 3: You want to replace entire path with a hard coded path:**

There's now no reason to use `Path.Combine`

```
"C:\SomeHardCodedRootDi\maincode.txt"
```

**Option n: Something I haven't thought of**

If none of the above answer your question, you could provide more detail on what you're trying to achieve (This will, as a side effect stop this question getting downvotes and close requests!!) and i'll do my best to answer the question by updating this answer.

Comment: Sorry for making myself unclear. I have made a string to a path. Basically i would like to move the txt file to a folder in program files. I have gone the long way round and used special folder and looked to find x86 or 32 bit program files etc and i have already created the string where i would like this txt to go. How can i add that string to the above?

Comment: @user1679564 - Then you want Option 2 (if its just the directory you have a string of) or Option 3 if it's the entire path and filename, just replace the whole call to `Path.Combine(...)`.